# Grunt BrowserSync + Angular getting "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" error

Tags: angularjs, iis, gruntjs, browser-sync

I have angular running on my localhost port 8080, and grunt browsersync running on port 3000.

I have in my grunt file:

```
browserSync: {    
            dev: {
                options: {
                    watchTask: true,
                     proxy: "localhost:8080"
                } 
            }
```

To get browsersync to work with the correct port. (I removed the bsFiles section since it's not relevant, but it's there in case anyone is wondering).

I currently have browsersync running perfectly fine with another project that uses just "localhost" as the proxy.

When I try to run the angular project I get:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
>   the contents of this directory.

I went ahead and completed all of IIS's suggestions with no luck:

> If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default
>   document is configured and that the file exists. 
> Enable directory
>   browsing using IIS Manager. 
> Open IIS Manager. In the Features view,
>   double-click Directory Browsing. 
> On the Directory Browsing page, in
>   the Actions pane, click Enable. 
> Verify that the
>   configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is
>   set to true in the site or application configuration file.

One interesting thing I noticed was this:

> Requested URL    //localhost:3000/ 
>  
>   Physical Path    C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot

Where I would think the requested url would be "localhost:8080" and phsyical path would be "wwwroot/myangularproject"

Please let me know if I could provide any more information!

Comment: I guess that if you want to change the port just do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614962/how-to-configure-port-in-browser-sync. Do not mess with the proxy settings.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that without any luck. I use the proxy because there's already a web server running the website. Is that the wrong way to do it?

Comment: Haven't done it myself so I do not know the "proper" way but proxy settings seem to be an overkill solution to me.